# Rinkeby ETH disappears after receiving it

Tags: ether, rinkeby

Ok , im not high yet , but any time i am using https://faucet.rinkeby.io/ to get some eth [3 eth to be exact],and
it gets immediately transferred out to different wallet without any interaction from my side. How is that possible ?  It is kind of scary.

https://rinkeby.etherscan.io/address/0xf39Fd6e51aad88F6F4ce6aB8827279cffFb92266

[image]

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Answer (score 1):

Tha facet did work.
Issue resolved , i used a hard hat account that i forgot about, it was imported to my metamask. Since its an open account with open private keys , someone created a bot that clears it out.

Comment: This should have been the first assumption. Glad you figured it out.

Answer (score 0):

That faucet hasn't worked for me or anyone I know in a while, I been using:

https://www.rinkebyfaucet.com/

https://faucets.chain.link/rinkeby (recommended)

The reason why I recommend the 2nd one is because you can run it several times to get the Eth you need.

When I started developing, I used a completely different wallet just in case.

Doesn't answer your question but I hope this helps you get going.